# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories) for user other than root

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

when I login with root user and go to the working directory (/home/gitproject), I have no issue running commands but when I login to the server with other users I get the following:

**fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**

How to resolve this issue?

the repo is not owned by **root** it is owner by **another user** and even when I use that user to login I get the same error!

Comment: I suspect that other users are not able to write (or perhaps even read) files and directories owned by `root`. You don't normally share a single local repository between multiple users. The ownership/permissions are going to be hard to get right.

Comment: the repo is not owner by root it is owner by another user and even when I use that user to login I get the same error!

Comment: Hmm `~/home/gitproject` ? Is there really a ~ there ? Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what's wrong here, but here are some advice on how to debug this. `git` does not find a the structure for a repository where you are, which means that it is unable to find either `/home/gitproject/.git` or `/home/.git` or `/.git`.

This may be because the files are missing or because only root can read them. Check with the users which do not work using the following command:

```
ls -l /home/gitproject/.git
```

(and so on).

On a side note, as `larks` mentioned in a comment, sharing a git repository is going to be a huge pain. Try `gitolite` or other projects of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

so I solved the issue ...
with root user I ran this command

```
rm -r .git
```

and logged in with another user and ran this:

```
git init
git remote set-url origin URL
```

It solved the issue. But still not clear what really happened there.